# Integral of sin(|x-y|)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I do not know how should I proceed to calculate the definite integral:
$$
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sin\left(\,{\left\lvert\,
{x - y\,}\right\rvert}\,\right)\,
\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
$$

Comment: **Hint:** $\int \sin(|x-y|)dx=-sgn(x-y)\cos(x-y)+C$.

Answer (score 2):

Use $\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2}\bigg(\int\limits_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{y}f(x,y)\mathop{dx}+\int\limits_{y}^{\frac{\pi}2}f(x,y)\mathop{dx}\bigg)\mathop{dy}$ to get rid of absolute value.

On each interval you have respectively $x\le y$ and $x\ge y$, can you see a big simplification coming ?